# href in a specific word of the String using JavaScript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show the content of `var fruits` (array) in a HTML page using li, ul, a and href for a specific word (not all the text).

For example, for the sentence `I want a link here` I want the link only for the word `here` but I don't know how to do it...

Here is the code so far:

```
<script>
// selects the div with an id of placeholder
var div = document.getElementById('placeholder');

// say that fruits contains all your data
var fruits = ['I want a link here','I want a link here','I want a link here','I want a link here','I want a link here'],
    ul = document.createElement('ul'); // create an arbitrary ul element

// loop through the fruits array
for(var i in fruits) {
        // create an arbitrary li element
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
         content = document.createTextNode(fruits[i]); // create a textnode to the document
         var link = "http://google.com";
         var element = document.createElement("a");
         element.setAttribute("href", link);
         element.innerHTML = fruits[i];

  li.appendChild(element); // append the created textnode above to the li element
  ul.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
}

div.appendChild(ul); // finally the ul element to the div with an id of placeholder
</script>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gka1hhpb/)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution

```
var div = document.getElementById('placeholder');

// say that fruits contains all your data
var fruits = ['I want a link <a href="#">here</a>','I want a link here','I want a link here','I want a link here','I want a link here'],
    ul = document.createElement('ul'); // create an arbitrary ul element

// loop through the fruits array
for(var i in fruits) {
        // create an arbitrary li element
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
         content = document.createTextNode(fruits[i]); // create a textnode to the document
         var link = "http://google.com";
         var element = document.createElement("span");

         element.innerHTML = fruits[i];

  li.appendChild(element); // append the created textnode above to the li element
  ul.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
}

div.appendChild(ul); // finally the ul element to the div with an id of placeholder
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gka1hhpb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your original data array you could use.

```
for(var i in fruits) {
        // create an arbitrary li element
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var link = "http://google.com";
  var content = fruits[i].replace('here', '<a href="'+ link  +'">here</a>');
  var element = document.createElement("span");

  element.innerHTML = content;

  li.appendChild(element); // append the created textnode above to the li element
  ul.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gka1hhpb/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This works in the fiddle you provided.

```
// selects the div with an id of placeholder
var div = document.getElementById('placeholder');

// say that fruits contains all your data
var fruits = ['I want a link here', 'I want a link here', 'I want a link here', 'I want a link here', 'I want a link here'],
  ul = document.createElement('ul'); // create an arbitrary ul element

// loop through the fruits array
for (var i in fruits) {
    // split words from sentence
    var fruitWords = fruits[i].split(' ');
  // select the word you want linked ( I selected 'here')
  var linkWord = fruitWords[fruitWords.length-1];
  // reconstruct sentence removing the linked word
  fruitWords.pop();
  fruits[i] = fruitWords.join(' ');

  // create an arbitrary li element
  var li = document.createElement('li'),
    content = document.createTextNode(fruits[i]); // create a textnode to the document
  var link = "http://google.com";

  var element = document.createElement("a");
  element.setAttribute("href", link);
  element.innerHTML = linkWord;
        li.innerHTML = fruits[i] + ' ';
  li.appendChild(element); // append the created textnode above to the li element
  ul.appendChild(li); // append the created li element above to the ul element
}

div.appendChild(ul); // finally the ul element to the div with an id of placeholder
```